# Return all records where column 2 is equal to 1 (in column 3) without searching in column 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database with lots of names in one column (and different spellings of each name) and would like to return all variations of one name. To do this I created a second (integer) column that has the same value as long as the same is just a variation.

### ID   |   Name   |   variation_nr

```
1   |  Aaron   |        1
2   |   Aron   |        1
3   |   Bob    |        2
```

What I want to do is to search for Aaron and for the program to return both Aaron and Aron.

What I have so far is `SELECT * FROM name WHERE name=$name;`

How can I get it to display all the names whose variation_nr is the same as the variation_nr of the name entered?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE SOUNDEX(name) = SOUNDEX('Aaron')` or `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name SOUNDS LIKE 'Aaron'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are able to use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM name
WHERE variation_nr IN (SELECT variation_nr FROM name WHERE name = $name);
```

Comment: That gives me the following error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: I am now getting the following error: Unknown column 'Aron' in 'where clause'. From what I know that is because there is an error in the WHERE part, however, my code looks just like yours.

Comment: Assuming you aren't using bound parameters, did you put single quotes around $name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` and join the table to it's self on the `variation_nr` fields like so:

```
SELECT `n2`.*
FROM `name` AS `n1`
INNER JOIN `name` AS `n2`
    ON (`n1`.`variation_nr` = `n2`.`variation_nr`)
WHERE `n1`.`name` = $name;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1fbe9/2/0)